# QGIS Server 3.4 - No labels in WMS

Tags: wms, qgis-3, qgis-server

I have successfully installed the current version of the QGIS Server on a Ubuntu 16.04. WFS, WCS run fine, but in WMS no text is rendered in the map. In the legend you can see text. Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

I have already installed several fonts on the server and tried them out, unfortunately without any results.

Comment: Did you try different WMS or just one? Have you seen this [Bug report #15440](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/15440)?

Comment: I don't remeber if I had tried different WMS-Version. Setting no font worked for me. It was okay for doing a workshop. It was an Ubuntu 16.04 maschine, so appears not related to your mentioned bug report.

Comment: Apparently, it contains some feedbacks about the Server part as well as Ubuntu.